# Remove duplicated objects from MongoDB query results

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation

I have an aggregation pipeline in mongo composed of a match and a project operation and I have an array of objects as a result.

An example of result:

```
[{"pdb_id":"1avy"},{"pdb_id":"1avy"},{"pdb_id":"1lwu"}]
```

I would like to remove duplicated objects, so the result should be:

```
[{"pdb_id":"1avy"},{"pdb_id":"1lwu"}]
```

An example of working solution is:

```
 const uniqueArray = result.filter((object,index) => index === result.findIndex(obj => JSON.stringify(obj) === JSON.stringify(object)));
```

But this is extremely slow when I have more data involved. Do you know a faster solution?

Please consider that the object in the result may also have more than one property. For example:

```
[{"pdb_id":"1avy", "pdb_chain":"A"},{"pdb_id":"1avy", "pdb_chain":"A"},{"pdb_id":"1lwu", "pdb_chain":"A"}]
```

Needs to be filtered to:

```
 [{"pdb_id":"1avy", "pdb_chain":"A"},{"pdb_id":"1lwu", "pdb_chain":"A"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to do it with Mongo's help you don't have much choice other than using `$group`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$$ROOT"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$_id"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Rpr_4FXcffL)

Obviously Mongo has some [limits](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-operator-and-memory), assuming you don't reach the 100 mb limit this should always be the faster option.